# R put for loop into vector

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I would like to put the output of the following for loop into a single vector.

```
test=c("A","B","C","D")
for(i in 1:3)
 {e=runif(1,5,10);
  f=round(e);
  g=sample(test,f,TRUE);
  h=paste(g,collapse = "");
    print(h)}
```

Output:

```
[1] "BDCCABD"
[1] "DDBAADBBAA"
[1] "DACCAB"
```

I would like to get a vector like:

```
i=c("BDCCABD","DDBAADBBAA","DACCAB")
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: In your loop, `h[i] = paste(g, collapse = "")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention vector, then let us using `vector`

```
V=vector()
test=c("A","B","C","D")
for(i in 1:3)
{e=runif(1,5,10);
f=round(e);
g=sample(test,f,TRUE);
h=paste(g,collapse = "");
V[i]=h}

V
[1] "BCCAD"     "CCDCACBAD" "ADCDBCBCC"
V[1]
[1] "BCCAD"
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick help

Comment: @WiebkeKn Yw~ :-) nice day

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight adaptation of your code will do it.

```
set.seed(8632)    # make the results reproducible

i <- sapply(1:3, function(x){
    e = runif(1, 5, 10)
    f = round(e)
    g = sample(test, f, TRUE)
    h = paste(g, collapse = "")
    print(h)
    h
})

i
#[1] "CACDAABCC" "ADDAACA"   "ACCDAACAB"
```

Do you really need to `print(h)`?

**EDIT.**
I've just tested it and the following simplification gives exactly the same result.

```
set.seed(8632)    # make the results reproducible

j <- sapply(1:3, function(x){
    f <- sample(5:10, 1)        # this is equivalent to your original code
    g = sample(test, f, TRUE)
    h = paste(g, collapse = "")
    print(h)
    h
})

j
#[1] "CACDAABCC" "ADDAACA"   "ACCDAACAB"

identical(i, j)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this:

```
test=c("A","B","C","D")
h_final<-0
for(i in 1:3){e=runif(1,5,10);
f=round(e);
g=sample(test,f,TRUE);
h=paste(g,collapse = "");
h_final[i]<-h
if(i==3){print(h_final)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
j <- character()

test = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
for (i in 1:3) {
  e = runif(1, 5, 10)
  f = round(e)
  g = sample(test, f, TRUE)
  h = paste(g, collapse = "")

  j <- c(j, h)
}

print(j)

> print(j)
[1] "DDDBADBCD" "ABBCBCC"   "BBCAA"
```

EDIT: Even simpler

```
test = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
for (i in 1:3) {
  e = runif(1, 5, 10)
  f = round(e)
  g = sample(test, f, TRUE)
  h[i] = paste(g, collapse = "")
  }

> print(h)
[1] "DBDADDD"  "AABDA"    "CDBDDABC"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [vectors in R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/vector)

You need to initialize an empty vector, let's call it `test_vector`

```
test_vector = c()
test=c("A","B","C","D")

for(i in 1:3)
    {e=runif(1,5,10);
    f=round(e);
    g=sample(test,f,TRUE);
    h=paste(g,collapse = "");
    print(h)
    test_vector <- c(test_vector,h)
    }
```

Note that you could apply a function to your `test` vector directly without using a for loop.

Comment: be careful, the iteration variable of the for-loop is also called `i`

Comment: You're right, I just took the same name as the OP without looking.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way especially if you have lots of iterations but it works:

```
test=c("A","B","C","D")
k = NA
for(i in 1:3)
{e=runif(1,5,10)
f=round(e)
g=sample(test,f,TRUE)
h=paste(g,collapse = "")
k = append(k,h)
print(h)}

k <- na.omit(k)
```